# React Chrome Extension: API response data can be viewed via React Chrome extension, is this alright?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Hi I am new to `React development`, and I am currently developing a `Django-React application` implementing `DRF`. I have installed a React Chrome extension to check some stuff but upon exploring I noticed that my API responses can be spied on via this Chrome extension.

I am now starting to think if I've integrated React well on my Django app. Is it normal and safe to have these response data available via the extension?

Here're some screenshots:

***Here is a NEWS section on the homepage which is loaded via React***
 [image]

***And someone can spy on the API data via React Chrome app***
[image]